# Load HTML (with document.write) into another HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have started making a hybrid mobile app using Cordova in Visual Studio. There is a part of a code that will be repeated on all the pages. I want to split the code into a separate file and load the file at the required div on every page.

I have tried ajax load, innerHTML, saving the file in js and loading it, but none of them work.

My code has a document.write command for printing the localstorage parameter and hence I am not able to load the html along with the localstorage parameter. It's only loading the HTML and ignoring the script part.

Please help.

This is my code:

```
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
          <script>document.write('<img src="'+localStorage.getItem("avatar_url_small")+'" class="user-image" alt="User Image">');</script>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p><script>document.write('<span class="hidden-xs">'+localStorage.getItem("name")+'</span>');</script></p>
          <a href="profile_edit.html"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Edit Profile</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- search form -->
      <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.search form -->
      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
        <li><a href="activity.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Activity</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="groups.html"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Groups</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <span>Events</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="blogs.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> <span>Blogs</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="files.html"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> <span>Files</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="bookmarks.html"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i> <span>Bookmarks</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="wire.html"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> <span>Wire Post</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="questions.html"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> <span>Questions</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="photo.html"><i class="fa fa-photo"></i> <span>Photos</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="video.html"><i class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i> <span>Videos</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

How can I split the file and load it on every page along with the document.write command and not just the HTML.

Comment: Please, do not use `document.write`...`ajax load` should works, maybe your implementation was faulty...but, do not use `document.write`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: _I am not able to load the html along with the localstorage parameter_ - Of course you can't, it runs on the client side, if you want a rendered HTML you must do it on the server side (Which is problematic since you save the data in localStorage....)